# Считать количество нажатых элементов

Tags: android, коллекции, kotlin

Есть некий метод, в котором я по нажатию элемента в коллекции определяю тот или иной элемент(*после чего выделяю его*).

Теперь же я хочу помимо того что просто выделяю данные элементы, паралелльно считать сколько я элементов выделил, вот собственно на данный момент мой первоначальный метод.

```
 private fun clickOnElement(guid: String, loginGuid: String) {
    tvItems[loginGuid]?.firstOrNull { it.guid == guid }?.let {
        it.selected = !it.selected
    }
    tvItems[loginGuid]?.let { calculateLoginState(loginGuid, it) }
    contract?.updateViewSubtitle(guid)
}
```

Собственно в контракте я пока определяю нажатие по тому или иному элементу и вывожу просто id.

Comment: возможно поможет решение отфильтровать выделенные элементы?
в java вроде это делается с помощью reduce, в kotlin'e же наверное поможет метод fold. И вы как бы можете вернуть ArrayList.

Answer (score -1):

Можно отфильтровать коллекцию и посчитать кол-во элементов.

```
tvItems.values.filter{ it.selected }.count()
```

Или если tvItems - это коллекция коллекций, то можно применить flatMap/flatten вначале.

Не по теме:

- На самом деле использование let наделает код более непонятным.
- Если tvItems хранит в себе коллекции, то удобнее бывает не хранить нулевые коллекции, а пустые (тогда не нужно делать проверку)

Как мог бы выглядеть код:

```
 private fun clickOnElement(guid: String, loginGuid: String) {
     val item = tvItems[loginGuid] ?: return
     item.selected = !item.selected
     calculateLoginState(loginGuid, item)
     val selected = tvItems.values.filter{ it.selected }
     //...
     contract?.updatedViewSubtitle(guid)
```

}